# (Python recursion) Getting all possible string combinations from *args(list of lists that contain strings):

Tags: python, loops, recursion, concatenation, args

I have the following code:

```
SIZES = ['small', 'medium', 'long']
COLORS = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
SHAPES = ['circle', 'triangle', 'square']


def string_concatenation(*args):
    pass
```

What I need to do is use recursion (call the function inside itself) to return a list of all possible combinations as a list of strings i.e.: `['small red circle', 'small blue circle',...,'long green triangle', 'long green square']`

I'm not allowed to use `itertools`. Any ideas?

Comment: any attempts so far?

Comment: none that worked... that's why i didn't post anything in the function body

Comment: I understand that none worked, but by posting an attempt you might get more help as users are more willing to contribute when a poster shows some initiative. it could also help by others pointing out the errors in your code.

Comment: This is not a problem where recursion is the natural or sensible choice.  A simple set of 3 nested loops makes this trivial, in about 5 lines of code.

Comment: @TimRoberts as you see, the function parameter is *args, so technically, this function has to manage any number of arguments. the three here are just an example

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it after studying recursion a bit:

```
def cartezian_product_recursive(*sets)
    if not sets:
        return ['']

    partial_solution = cartezian_product_recursive(*sets[1:])
    solution = []

    for set_element in sets[0]:
        for partial_solution_element in partial_solution:
            solution.append(f'{set_element} {partial_solution_element}'.rstrip(' '))

    return solution
```